# Binding Event Handler Attribute onclick 2 times with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onclick, closures

I am a beginner to JavaScript and currently going through the ***The Complete Reference 3rd Edition by Thomas A. Powell , Fritz Schneider***.
I quote an abstract from the same book.

[image]
The author goes to provide a solution for this which is listed as below:

```
<p id="p1">Please click me!</p>

<script>

function addEvent(obj,event,handler) {

    var oldHandler = obj[event];
    if (typeof obj[event] != "function")
    {
        obj[event] = handler;
    }
    else
    {
        obj[event] = function () {
        if (oldHandler) { oldHandler.apply(); }
        handler.apply();
   }
  }
}

var el = document.getElementById("p1");

function click1() { alert("First click handler"); }
function click2() { alert("Second click handler"); }

addEvent(el,"onclick",click1);
addEvent(el,"onclick",click2);


</script>
```

Being a newbie into the JavaScript world, I tried debugging it to make it better explainable to myself. I notice(at this point, I haven't clicked on the paragraph) when the control comes to `addEvent(el,"onclick",click1);` within the ***function addEvent***, ***obj[event]*** sets itself to ***click1***; then the control goes outside the function.

For the **second call to the same function**, ***variable oldHandler*** has still the old value(assigned to it in the first call) which is ***= obj[event] = click1***. So, is it due to the concept of closures or am I missing out something? Kindly help!

Answer (score 0):

Each call to addEvent, overwrites the previous handler with a wrapper function. Each wrapper function overwrites the old one, and each wrapper holds a reference to the old one, and invokes it prior to invoking the provided handler. This allowes you to stack many wrappers, one on top of the other, where each handler invokes the previous wrapper, then the newset provided handler. Each function retains its state via closure.

However this is no longer required. In modern browsers you can simply use addEventListener which does not overwrite other handlers.

Comment: the author makes mentioon of the addEventListener in just the coming section.